# io unsupported operation for python

Tags: python, io

I have a problem in python where i type the code below and gives me the `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable` error.
here's the code:

```py
 string = "set style vintage"
 new_style = line_4.replace("set style","")
 with open("style.txt","w") as set_style:
     set_style.write(str(new_style))
```

I converted to string and nothing was fixed

Comment: This error is raised if you write to a file opened in read mode, but your code does not reflect that.

Comment: is it now anymore good?

Comment: I think its a problem with the whole source code.